# Как после использования переменной в классе использовать следущую

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

пишу квест в тг боте, создал класс для отправки вопроса, ответа и инлайн кнопок, вопрос, ответ и кнопки q1 он отправляет, но я не знаю как после нажатия ответа отправлять новый вопрос q2. Просто в квесте больше 40 таких вопросов. Можете подсказать пожалуйста как после ответа отправлять новый вопрос.

Вот код https://github.com/Lonndy007/tgbotquest